# Developing VSTO Add-ins for Skype

Tags: vsto, add-in, skype-for-business

Is it possible to develop VSTO add-ins for Skype? There are multiple articles on the internet that talk about creating Add-ins for other office products like Outlook, Word, Excel etc., but none for Skype. Could someone point me to some help content for developing add-ins for Skype?